# Javascript Scoring

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a scoring sheet for a quiz I am making. I have created the code to print out how many they got right when they press the submit button. However, when I run it and press the submit button, nothing happens.
This is the code I have so far.

```
var correct = 0;
var incorrect = 0;

function Answers(){
if (QuestA1 == "answersA1") {
   correct++;
}
if (QuestA2 == "answersA2") {
   correct++;
}
if (QuestA3 == "answersA3") {
   correct++;
}
if (QuestA4 == "answersA4") {
   correct++;
}
if (QuestA5 == "answersA5") {
   correct++;
}
if (QuestA6 == "answersA6") {
   correct++;
}
if (QuestA7 == "answersA7") {
   correct++;
}
if (QuestA8 == "answersA8") {
   correct++;
}
if (QuestA9 == "answersA9") {
   correct++;
}
if (QuestA10 == "answersA10") {
   correct++;

    }

  }
<input type="button" value="Sumbit your answers" onclick=Answers()/>
```

the function is in the `<script>` tag and the button is in the body.

Comment: Where are you printing the counters?

Comment: General note use === instead of == because == does some strange type conversions. See the section on = == === in [jslint](http://jslint.com/help.html) for why the type conversion is bad.

Comment: oh, I forgot to add counters would I put that the same place as 'var correct'? and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it to this:

```
onclick="Answers()"
```

Comment: It still isn't working. 'QuestA1' is the name of my button and when I do the inspect on Chrome is says that QuestA1 is not defined. Have I put the wrong thing in for it to work?

Comment: The only other code I have is the buttons, answers and just HTML to change the layout

Comment: Where is the function to display how many questions they got right?

Comment: I haven't got a function for that, I'm new to all this sorry. How would I make a function for that?

Comment: If you can add the rest of your html and javascript ill try and help

Comment: The submit button now works, however the score is just 0, and I have made no changed to the JavaScript above. I don't know what I'm missing to allow it to add the score?

Comment: Where are these answers stored and the questions?